# systemd user mode simulation

Tags: rhel, systemd, daemon

I am using Red Hat 7.2 and I need to run user daemon. As said here https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1293513 Red Hat 7 doesn't support user mode of systemd.
My main goal is to start different instance of single daemon that will be used by owner user. Can anyone suggest some alternative ways of doing this without systemd user mode?

Comment: The document needs login, not worth. Why can't simply use polkit rules? At least Arch supports it.

Answer (score 2):

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1293513, after discussing --user, says RH doesn't generally support the ability of regular users to stop and start system daemons;  it then goes on to show how to set up sudo to allow those users to become admin to start a given daemon (like a log daemon which runs as root).  But the article misses the crux of OP's question, which seems to be allowing a user to control a process in systemd running as that user; not a system daemon but a user-level daemon.  --User touches on it but the article veers off quickly on a tangent.

I suspect they want you to figure out that copies of a given service can be started as root but then drop permissions and become a user for the duration of the command.  You need to find out how to drop from root to (eg) testuser ID and permissions, just as the moin service starts.

In short:  a user will need to elevate to root to enable or control a daemon that itself drops to a user permissions as part of the start script.  Many daemons (eg ntpd -u) will drop permissions as part of invocation, and via that method we can have users controlling user daemons without using the --user part of the systemd fridge-art that RH itself even hates.

Yes, it briefly becomes root, and yes, that's a security concern; and yes, it'd be better if the parent company supported all the pieces of its favourite son's favourite son.  But we have what we have.

Answer (score 2):

For most use-cases (e.g. having the user manage their own unit files), systemd 219 for RHEL7 works fine, you just have to enable it. Tableau Server for Linux, for example, ships with a user service that enables the user instance:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/user@29575.service
[Unit]
Description=User Manager for UID %i
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
# These are present in the RHEL8 version of this file except that the unit is Requires, not Wants.
# It's listed as Wants here so that if this file is used in a RHEL7 settings, it will not fail.
# If a user upgrades from RHEL7 to RHEL8, this unit file will continue to work until it's
# deleted the next time they upgrade Tableau Server itself.
After=user-runtime-dir@%i.service
Wants=user-runtime-dir@%i.service

[Service]
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
User=%i
PAMName=systemd-user
Type=notify
# PermissionsStartOnly is deprecated and will be removed in future versions of systemd
# This is required for all systemd versions prior to version 231
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/loginctl enable-linger %i
ExecStart=-/lib/systemd/systemd --user
Slice=user-%i.slice
KillMode=mixed
Delegate=yes
TasksMax=infinity
Restart=always
RestartSec=15

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

You'll still need an XDG_RUNTIME_DIR in `.bashrc` or `.profile` when interacting with the instance:

```
# cat /home/$(id -un 29575)/.bashrc
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}" ] && export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -ru)
```

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl enable user@29575.service
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/user@29575.service to /etc/systemd/system/user@29575.service.
# systemctl start user@29575.service

# su -l -s /bin/bash -c "systemctl --user status" $(id -un 29575)
● hostname
    State: running
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 0 units
    Since: Tue 2020-09-22 12:12:48 UTC; 5min ago
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-29575.slice/user@29575.service
           ├─18802 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
           └─18804 (sd-pam)
```

Courtesy of https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3461241